# How to get top most UIViewController on entire iPhone (not just in my application)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I can totally see why Apple wouldn't allow something like this, but is it at all possible to get the active UIViewController of the entire iPhone (when your app is running in the background)?

Just as a read-only kind of thing? Even have a UIScreen know what view controllers are on it??

I suspect this can't be done, but maybe we can discuss it a little.

Comment: Can't be done (at least with public, app-store approved APIs).

Comment: @rmaddy this is posted as a comment, but does in fact answer the question. (See what I did there?)